# Deploying Laravel with Docker, Nginx, Let's Encrypt SSL and Supervisor

Tags: laravel, docker, nginx, github-actions, devops

I am very new to containerizing approach of deploying applications. I am trying to deploy my Laravel app to Azure using Docker and ACI. I couldn't find any well explained articles or articles matching my requirements of deployment.

I am actually trying to setup a proper DevOps pipeline, with sequence being: I push my code to GitHub, Run GitHub Actions, Build Docker Image, Push to ACR and Pull in ACI.

I attempted to build the Laravel docker image in my local environment with Nginx and Supervisor in a single image and it works well. But now I want to use automated Let's Encrypt SSL in my Nginx server. If I rebuild the image every time requesting a new SSL certificate for my server with `certbot` that wouldn't be a right idea, right? So, what is the best way to do it?

Here is my current Dockerfile without SSL:

```
# Use the official PHP 8.1 image as the base image
FROM php:8.1-fpm

# Install necessary packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git zip unzip supervisor libpng-dev libonig-dev libxml2-dev libzip-dev nginx

# Full update system
RUN apt-get upgrade -y

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql gd mbstring exif pcntl bcmath zip

# Set the working directory to /var/www/html
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Copy the Laravel application files to the container
COPY . .

# Copy the Nginx configuration file
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

# Install Composer and run it to install the application dependencies
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN composer install --no-dev --no-interaction

# Copy the environment file
RUN cp .env.example .env

# Generate the application key
RUN php artisan key:generate

# Set the ownership and permissions of the application files
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html

# Copy the Supervisor configuration file
COPY supervisor.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/mysupervisor.conf

# Expose port 80 for the Nginx web server
EXPOSE 80

# Start Nginx and Supervisor
CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c" , "service nginx restart && /usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf"]
```

Comment: Show us the Nginx Dockerfile